# 3x3 squares on a $m\times n$ board without overlap

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, tiling

Considering a $n\times m$ board and all possible 3x3 squares on the board, 1 square is chosen and random and excluded from the $n\times m$ board. How many $3x3$ are possible on the remaining board?

One of the key notes is in a 5x5 board, there are 9 possible square locations, but any one will block out all the others.

Also notice that a 6x6 has the same area as a 4x9 and 3x12.

A 6x6 has 16 possible squares, and max squares (S) $1\leq S\leq 4$

A 4x9 has 14 possible squares, and max squares (S) $2\leq S\leq 3$

A 3x12 has 10 possible squares, and max squares (S) $2\leq S\leq 4$

The main question was, what is the expected number of squares on average?

Would it help if n and m were bounded by 100?

Is the optimal solution a multiple of 3 for m and n?

What would be the best way to learn more about this kind of question/topic?

Comment: A lower bound on the expected number of squares is $\frac{(m-2)(n-2)}{25}$, by the [Turán's theorem argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities#Tur.C3.A1n.27s_theorem): if we randomly sort the $(m-2)(n-2)$ possible square locations, and consider them in that order (one way to think about adding squares at random), then a square is definitely added if it was sorted before all squares that overlap with it, which happens with probability $\frac1{25}$ or better.